# Angular using templateUrl or HTML templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've struggled to find any information on this online, so here goes:

In an angular app, there are several options to include templates. Depending on the use of the application, different methods might prove superior. In my case, I'm writing an application where most pages are going to be viewed every time the application is used.

My current approach is using the `$routeProvider` approach with a `templateUrl` for each view, which leads to fetching multiple .html files at various stages. This does, in my opinion, put unnecessary load on the webserver.

Is there another option to include the full content in a single request, which conforms to angular best practices?

My current best idea is to include all templates in the index file, and use `ng-if` to only display the current relevant view.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth taking a look at [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), which could be injected into a TemplateService (such as the below); the job of the service being to load whatever files are passed to it. You could inject the service into a top level controller and cache any files you might need later on:

**MainCtrl**

```
app.controller('MyMainCtrl', ['TemplateService', function(TemplateService) {
    /* Specify templates to be loaded */
    var templates = [ '/foo.html', '/bar.html' ];

    /* Fetch and cache each template */
    _.each(templates, function(template) {
       TemplateService.loadTemplate(template)
           .done(function() {
                console.log('Loaded template: ' + template);
           });
    });
}]);
```

**TemplateService**

```
app.service('TemplateService', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
        loadTemplate: function(template) {
            var deferred = new $.Deferred();

            /* Check if the template is already been loaded */
            if ($templateCache.get(template)) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                var options = {
                    async: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: template
                };
                /* Fetch template */
                $.ajax(options)
                    .done(function (response) {
                        $templateCache.put(template, response);
                        deferred.resolve();
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        console.log('Unable to load template: ' + template);
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
            }
            return deferred.promise();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: My whole issue with the current "selerate html file per template" approach is that it creates multiple concurrent requests to the webserver. If I can aggregate several templates into just one, I think it would improve the response time a lot (as I'm not using SPDY). Caching partially solves this, but I was wondering if there was another approach - like caching 8 templates using only 1 request.

Comment: Using nginx (or some other async server) to serve static content essentially nullifies any worry of generating too many requests. These files are text and the load on the server would be negligible. Now if you were pulling these templates from a database, that'd be a different story. Also, the HTTP protocol states 1 request results in 1 response, so unless you're zipping the templates on the server, you'll need to issue N GET requests to get back N templates - unless you lump all the templates into a single HTML file and then somehow parse back on the JS side, which would be way too messy

Comment: Can you elaborate on why lumping all templates into a single HTML file would be too messy? During development they could be seperate files - on production aggregated using the script tag method from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache.
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">template1</script><script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">template2</script>

Comment: Come to think of it, all templates could be wrapped into json and stored in the cache using $templateCache.put

Comment: As long as you have separate files (template1.html, template2.html, etc), you'll need to fetch them individually from the server, there's no way around it, unless you zip of course, so no matter where you put the script tags (bundled on a single page or not), they will always each result in single GET to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly legitimate way to do it  the route provider is there to handle what to load when.
When you enter a new route, angular will destroy the old one and load the new one, so it's not like all of your templates are in the DOM at the same time, same goes with ng-if.

If you feel like your application is going to be very large and include a ton of view you can look into lazy loading with angular and something like Requirejs. If you take that route I'd wait a few weeks for Angular 1.4 and the new router they are releasing for it